# Unclear understand of ? : in swift syntax

Tags: swift, syntax

I can't quite comprehend this syntax in the return statement.  I'm not sure if it is new in Swift 2.0, but what does the ? and the : mean?  Is this question mark an optional, even though spaced?  Im quite confused, coming from an Objective-C background.

```
private func doContainsUser(user: User) -> Bool {
    let isInverted = setOfDiff.contains(user)
    let wasInitiallyAdded = setOfCircleUsers.contains(user)

    //What does the ? and the : mean?
    return isInverted ? !wasInitiallyAdded : wasInitiallyAdded
}
```

Comment: Ternary operator (see also conditional operator, inline if (iif), or ternary if.). More info there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:
In other words: if (isInverted){return !!wasInitiallyAdded}else{ return wasInitiallyAdded} Swift Doc (that explain it also): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID71

Comment: Really? It is _exactly_ the same in Objective-C! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: Why would you not just `return wasInitiallyAdded ^ isInverted`

Comment: @Larme To be clear, this is not *the* ternary operator. This is the *conditional operator*, which is *a* ternary operator. But it also happens to be the only ternary operator at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a short hand if else statement.

```
if isInverted {
   return !wasInitiallyAdded
}
else {
   return wasInitiallyAdded
}
```

Comment: oh makes so much sense now.  thank u